# How to compose a question from the following statement?

Tags: interrogatives

I have this statement:

> "The synthetic element number 99, Einsteinium, is named after the
>   famous scientist Albert Einstein."

Now I'm interested to create a question from this statement, then what
is the way to do it correctly? This is my attempt:

> "After whom the element number 99 is named"?

Is it considered correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways you can ask this question

> After whom is element 99 named?
>   Element 99 is named after whom?
>   Element 99 is named for whom?

The answer to these questions is

> Element 99 is named after/for Einstein.

Answer (score 2):

> After whom *was* the element number 99 named?

is the correct form. The way you wrote it doesn't follow the word order of a question. It reads like a partial statement. For example:

> Einstein is the person *after whom the element number 99 was named*.

Use *was* as it is clearly refers to a past occurrence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it's still named after him. isn't it?

Comment: I think both was and is are defensible. Thinking of the naming as a point-in-time decision, like a little ceremony or something, you'd use "was". But being named something is an ongoing state, so you can use "is". In contrast, consider "christened", which is only a point-in-time naming event. So you could only say "I *was* christened" but you can say "I *am*" or "I *was*" named.